# Detect compiler with #ifdef

Tags: c++, exception, c-preprocessor, pgi

I'm trying to build a small code that works across multiple platforms and compilers. I use assertions, most of which can be turned off, but when compiling with PGI's `pgicpp` using `-mp` for OpenMP support, it automatically uses the `--no_exceptions` option: everywhere in my code with a "throw" statement generates a fatal compiler error. ("support for exception handling is disabled")

Is there a `define`d macro I can test to hide the `throw` statements on PGI? I usually work with gcc, which has `GCC_VERSION` and the like. I can't find any documentation describing these macros in PGI.

Comment: clang http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658461/what-predefined-macro-can-i-use-to-detect-clang | VC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127522/how-to-ifdef-by-compilertype-gcc-or-vc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the [Pre-defined C/C++ Compiler Macros](http://predef.sourceforge.net/index.php) project on Sourceforge.

PGI's compiler has a `__PGI` macro.

Also, take a look at [libnuwen's](http://nuwen.net/libnuwen.html) compiler.hh header for a decent way to 'normalize' compiler versioning macros.

Comment: Second link is dead :(

Answer (score 4):

You could try this to see what macros are predefined by the compiler:

```
pgcc -dM
```

Maybe that will reveal a suitable macro you can use.

Comment: Indeed.  The output of that is shown at http://www.pgroup.com/support/tprs_70.htm, and there's __PGI (mentioned above), and __PGIC__, __PGIC_MINOR__, and __PGIC_PATCHLEVEL__, which give the major, minor, and patchlevel parts of the compiler version number.

Comment: And there's the joy of the parser taking double underscores and doing entertaining things with them.  'PGI' is prefixed with double underscores; the other three are both prefixed and suffixed with them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the boost headers? Supposing they support PGI, they will have found a way to detect it. You could use that. I would start to search somewhere in `boost/config`.