# What predefined macro can I use to detect clang?

Tags: c, macros, clang, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to detect the compiler used to compile my source code. I can easily find predefined macros to check for MSVC or GCC (see https://github.com/cpredef/predef for example), but I cannot find any macro to check for clang.

Does someone know if clang defines a macro like `__CLANG__` in order to know what is currently compiling my code ?

Comment: http://predef.sourceforge.net/precomp.html#sec4

Comment: [Updated list of compiler macros](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Found the answer using `strings` + `grep` :

```
$ strings /usr/bin/clang | grep __ | grep -i clang
__clang__
```

Answer (score 135):

To get a list of all the predefined macros that the compiler uses, use this:

```
clang -dM -E -x c /dev/null
```

You can do the same for gcc.

Answer (score 44):

This question has been answered for years but let me add (for future reference) how it is done in **Windows**:

```
echo | clang -dM -E -
```

same as for GCC:

```
echo | gcc -dM -E -
```

Please note: The last dash `-` is actually important! (Otherwise you get `error: no input files` for both compilers)

Comment: FYI, Windows equivalent of `/dev/null` is `NUL:`

Comment: @legalize Whoa! I didn't know that! That's pretty cool; where'd you find that?

Comment: It's been there since the DOS days, just most DOS/Windows users never needed it.

Comment: This is what I usually do in Linux as well.  Typing `/dev/null` is more work.