# Detect gcc as opposed to msvc / clang with macro

Tags: c++, gcc

I am working on a project that has been built with both gcc and msvc so far. We recently started building with clang as well.

There are some parts in the code, where platform-specific things are done:

```
#ifndef _WIN32
// ignore this in msvc
#endif
```

Since gcc has previously been the only non-windows build, this was equivalent to saying "do this only for gcc". But now it means "do this only for gcc and clang".

However there are still situations, where I would like to handle something specifically for gcc, and not for clang. Is there a simple and robust way to detect gcc, i.e.

```
#ifdef ???
// do this *only* for gcc
#endif
```

Comment: Why are you building with a multitude of compilers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to #ifdef by CompilerType ? GCC or VC++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127522/how-to-ifdef-by-compilertype-gcc-or-vc)

Comment: nope, the other question does not even mention clang...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What predefined macro can I use to detect clang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658461/what-predefined-macro-can-i-use-to-detect-clang) for clang + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127522/how-to-ifdef-by-compilertype-gcc-or-vc for VC

Comment: You are confusing operating systems and compilers.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
__GNUC__
__GNUC_MINOR__
__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__
```

> These macros are defined by all GNU compilers that use the C preprocessor: C, C++, Objective-C and Fortran. Their values are the major version, minor version, and patch level of the compiler, as integer constants. For example, GCC 3.2.1 will define __GNUC__ to 3, __GNUC_MINOR__ to 2, and __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ to 1. These macros are also defined if you invoke the preprocessor directly.

Also:

```
__GNUG__
```

> The GNU C++ compiler defines this. Testing it is equivalent to testing (__GNUC__ && __cplusplus).

[Source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)

Apparently, `clang` uses them too. However it also defines:

```
__clang__
__clang_major__
__clang_minor__
__clang_patchlevel__
```

So you can do:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
    #ifndef __clang__
...
```

Or even better (note the order):

```
#if defined(__clang__)
....
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__GNUG__)
....
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
....
```

Comment: These things are all collected in the much more robust [Boost.Predef](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/predef/doc/html/index.html), and the (now outdated) original wiki that sprung that Boost library is located [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/).
Note that the Intel compiler will define `__GNUC__` or `_MSC_VER` on the relevant platforms as well.

Comment: All compilers that support the GNU C set of language extensions define those macros, right down to `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__`.  So to detect support for a specific GNU C feature on any compiler, you check those macros.  On gcc itself, they also map to the actual version of the compiler you're using, but they're best used to tell you what version of the GNU C language is supported, more than the compiler type / version.

Comment: This does not seem to work when using clang-cl. In this case `__clang__` and `_MSC_VER` is defined.

Comment: `__clang__`, `__clang_major__`, `__clang_minor__` and `__clang_patchlevel__` are all defined on gcc. What kind of sadistic maniac would design it that way?

Comment: @Badasahog Pardon ? Clang emulates either GCC or MSVC, not the other way around!

Comment: @JohanBoulé they both emulate each other

Comment: @Badasahog I insist that GCC does NOT define `__clang__`. Where did you see that happen ?

Comment: @JohanBoulé I tested it myself

Comment: @Badasahog The only explanation is you had a glitch in you test. Again, GCC does not define `__clang__`, so the compiler that you tested was either really Clang or something else than GCC.

Comment: When `GNUG` is equivalent to `GNUC && cpp` then it's useless to test for both: `GNUC || GNUG` <=> `GNUC || GNUC && cpp` <=> `GNUC && (1 || cpp)` <=> `GNUC`...

Comment: there is an easier macro for clang: `__clang_version__` and it produces something like `3.2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final)`

Answer (score 15):

I use this define:

```
#define GCC_COMPILER (defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__))
```

And test with it:

```
#if GCC_COMPILER
...
#endif
```

Comment: That won't exclude ICC.

Comment: @PeterCordes why not

Comment: @Ayxan: because ICC supports GNU extensions, and thus defines `__GNUC__`.  You'd also have to check for `!defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)`, like for clang.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/281802

Answer (score 11):

With Boost, this becomes very simple:

```
#include <boost/predef.h>

#if BOOST_COMP_GNUC
// do this *only* for gcc
#endif
```

See also the [Using the predefs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/predef/doc/index.html#_using_the_predefs) section of the boost documentation.

(credit to rubenvb who mentioned this in a comment, to Alberto M for adding the include, and to Frederik Aalund for correcting `#ifdef` to `#if`)

Comment: The header to include to get the symbol is `<boost/predef.h>`.

Comment: You're supposed to use `#if BOOST_COMP_GNUC` and *not* `#ifdef` since the macro is *always* defined (but may be zero). See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/predef/using_the_predefs.html

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out, I thought I tested this when I first posted the answer, but it looks like `#ifdef` probably never worked, at least not for boost versions 1.55 or later.

Comment: Note that using Boost isn't always the correct solution. Boost can be handy, indeed, but thanks to its size and complexity, can add a large amount of overhead.#