# Recognizing clang, gcc, and tcc by implementation-defined macros

Tags: c, gcc, macros, clang, tcc

I use `clang`, `gcc`, and `tcc`, and I'd like to be able to differentiate between the three in a common header.

Judging by their macro dumps, I expect that the presence of the 
`__clang__` macro will uniquely identify clang.

I'm unable to get a macro dump with `tcc` ( `$compiler -x c -E -dM /dev/null` doesn't work in its case ).

What is the macro(s) (if any) that will uniquely identify gcc (and possibly tcc)?

Comment: Maybe `__GNUC__`?

Comment: There are duplicates for gcc, you should really ask only about tcc.

Comment: @KerrekSB clang defines `__GNUC__` too.

Comment: I'm afrais [tag:clang] redefine the whole set of predefined macros of [tag:gcc]. So quite difficult to isolate [tag:gcc]. I don't know about [tag:tcc].

Comment: @PSkocik:  Ah, no luck then. Clang isn't even licensed under a GNU license... Maybe `defined(__GNU__) && !defined(__clang__)`?

Comment: @PSkocik if gnuc and !clang

Comment: @2501 That works. I checked, and `tcc` doesn't define `__GNUC__`. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Wouldn't it be much more preferable not to rely on compiler-specific quirks and instead stick to the C++ standard? If you really have to test e.g. for the presence of a certain feature, the right question to ask would be how to do that...

Comment: @MartinHierholzer "If you really have to test e.g. for the presence of a certain feature, the right question to ask would be how to do that...", it would , but I'm not sure if there's a good answer to that one.  I know there's autoconf, but I don't want to use anything that combines feature detection with building,& I don't want to run a script per project. Ideally, I'd want something that keeps and updates a macro-based feature list in a global header, and the features macros it would expose would be dependent on the environment (compiler, feature test macros) in which I would include it.

Comment: @MartinHierholzer For now, simply switching actions based on the current compiler seems easier, although it is a kind of a hack.

Comment: @MartinHierholzer: sticking to the C++ standard is a very bad idea for **C** code!

Comment: Sorry, I misread the tag, this is about C and not C++. Still, sticking to the standard might be a good idea, if possible. It just will be a lot harder than in C++. Maybe rethink your choice of language ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use __TINYC__ to detect tcc<sup>1</sup>.

Detection of gcc and clang is explained in this StackOverflow question: [Detect gcc as opposed to msvc / clang with macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166565/detect-gcc-as-opposed-to-msvc-clang-with-macro)

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: http://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html#SEC9)
  __TINYC__ is a predefined macro to 1 to indicate that you use TCC.