# Flag to check whether the compiler is gcc/mingw or VC++ cl?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, mingw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect compiler with #ifdef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233435/detect-compiler-with-ifdef)

Greetings all,

I've been working on a C++ project using gcc on linux and mingw on windows.Now I want to use VC++ cl compiler on Windows.
I was to keep the same source code tree only change the compiler specific logic like:

```
#ifdef VC_CL_COMPILER
 //do vc++ related
#elif MINGW_FLAG
 //do mingw related
#elseif GCC_FLAG
  //do gc related    
#endif
```

Anyway tips on doing this?

Comment: Reason for reopening: I think gcc deserves a special case, as the `__GNUC__` flag is defined also by other compilers. See [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/#gcc-cc).

Answer (score 12):

Compilers usually have a predefined macro for this.

```
#if defined(__GCC__)
  //do gcc related
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
  //do msvc related
#else

#endif
```

Comment: Gcc v4.1 ( and probably others) doesn't define `__GCC__` .

It is `__GNUC__` that should be tested.