# How to #ifdef by CompilerType ? GCC or VC++

Tags: c, conditional-compilation

I used `#ifdef Win32` for safe calls alike `sprintf_s` but now I want to build project with MinGW and it's just wrong now. I need to use `#ifdef VC++` or somehow like that. Is it possible?

Comment: As an aside, you could just use `snprintf()` which is a standard function that does the same thing.

Comment: @FatalError Not in Visual C++, it doesn't; Alas there is only C89 support, and `snprintf` wasn't guaranteed to exist in C89. There's the similar `_snprintf`, though IIRC that wasn't renamed to `snprintf` because that does something subtly different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the "Microsoft-Specific Predefined Macros" table of [Visual C predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28VS.80%29.aspx)

You could check for `_MSC_VER`.

Answer (score 58):

```
#ifdef __clang__
/*code specific to clang compiler*/
#elif __GNUC__
/*code for GNU C compiler */
#elif _MSC_VER
/*usually has the version number in _MSC_VER*/
/*code specific to MSVC compiler*/
#elif __BORLANDC__
/*code specific to borland compilers*/
#elif __MINGW32__
/*code specific to mingw compilers*/
#endif
```

Comment: `__GNUC__` is a language dialect, not a compiler. Most compilers (Clang and ICC included) will define `__GNUC__` at least sometimes.

Comment: @Quuxplusone `__GNUC__` is a language dialect, but the code you write is usually for the compiler and hopefully humans. However, if you meant that I have to improve this answer by changing `/* code for GNU C compiler */` to `/* code in GNU C Dialect */` then, you may submit a proposal for improvement

Comment: Just pointing out that if the OP was trying to distinguish GCC from VC++ from "some other compiler also supporting GNU C" (e.g. ICC, Clang, Green Hills, ...) then checking `__GNUC__` would be insufficient. In that case, [this question/answer would fit their situation better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28166605/1424877).

Comment: FYI on macos, clang defines the gcc flag, so you need to do some extra logic like: #if __GNUC__
#ifndef __clang__
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wclass-memaccess"
#endif
#endif

Comment: Ah - I see you put clang first, thus avoiding the issue of clang enabling __GNUC__ nice

Comment: the last #else should probably have a static_assert(0,"Need compiler specific code for..."); for that day someone suddenly needs say... the intel compiler or some other compiler.

Answer (score 8):

Preferably, you should resort to using portable symbols. I understand sometimes those symbols may not be defined, so you can see the [Predef project](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) for an extensive list of preprocessor macros regarding standards, compilers, libraries, operating systems and architectures that *aren't* portable.

However, the function you specifically mention in this question has been included within the C11 standard as a part of [Annex K.3, the bounds-checking interfaces (library)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3).

[K.3.1.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.1.1p2) states:

> The functions, macros, and types declared or defined in K.3 and its subclauses are declared and defined by their respective headers if `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` is defined as a macro which expands to the integer constant 1 at the point in the source file where the appropriate header is first included

Thus, you should place preference upon checking `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__`, and only use compiler-specific symbols when that doesn't exist.

Comment: Nice. Never heard of that link before, thanks for posting it.