# #ifdef MINGW32 then ...don't compile this

Tags: mingw, conditional-compilation, preprocessor-directive

I would like to add compiler directives in the code to say, if we compile with mingw, then don't take this piece of code into consideration.

For example:

```
#ifdef _MINGW32_   //if this defined then don't compile the code
int x;
code....
#endif
```

Is it possible? How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect compiler with #ifdef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233435/detect-compiler-with-ifdef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#ifndef`, (or `#if ! defined`) does the opposite of `#ifdef`.